# Zip email with con AppleScript

Tags: mail.app, email, applescript, zip

I need to zip all email that have in the body this words "Identificativo messaggio: CA3DA789.008822A5.C33F80AE".
I have many email in AppleMail  so i think if it's possible to create an AppleScript that select all email that have in their body this Word "Identificativo messaggio: CA3DA789.008822A5.C33F80AE".
Once AppleScript find these mails,  unzip them and tell me where Save the file zip and with witch name.
It's possible to create this AppleScript ?

Every day i must zip the email and with search box i need of much time. So i think to use an AppleScript that work in this mode: I select an mail that contain "identificativo n. *****" and Applescript find all Mail with the same "identificativo n. *****". After selected mail, i could zip these files or stamp with their attachements.

Comment: Anything is possible in AppleScript. It's a script language used to do stuff in folders, and many other graphical projects

Comment: If you want to add additional information to the question, you can just edit the question directly using the "edit" link at its bottom.

Comment: Your question is unclear: Do you want to unzip attachments (or zip mails - which doesn't make much sense)? Also show us your own research and how far you got with your Apple Script!

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly possible to do this with AppleScript, but depending on how often you need to do this it might be simpler to just

- Use the search box within Mail to list all mails containing this specific string
- Drag them into a folder on the Desktop
- Compress/zip that folder